# How to create a UIView in circle Shape

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to make a `UIImage` in a circle shape like  [this](http://imagesup.net/?di=5137917505311) and many other shapes and save to photo album can any one suggest me how to do this?

Comment: dont think that is possible. Why is that required ? Maybe we can suggest other options if you provide more details on requirements.

Comment: I want to make an uiimage round and add it on other image

Comment: So have a square image, and when you display in you want it to be round (as shown in the link). Have a look at image masking.